# Programatically click a button on webpage?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the button code:

```
<button class="ncss-btn-black fs16-sm ncss-brand pb3-sm pl5-sm pr5-sm pt3-sm mr3-sm u-uppercase css-1n4ymyz" data-test="qa-cart-checkout">Checkout</button>
```

I have tried the following;

```
document.querySelector("button[data-test='qa-cart-checkout']”).click();
```

But I get the following error;

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help, thanks.

I need the answer in modern dom or jquery.

Comment: Your first `'` is funky and doesn't match the second one.  I'm assuming that's the issue and it's a parsing issue

Comment: Notice the error isn't complaining about `click`. It says: `'button[data-test=‘qa-cart-checkout']' is not a valid selector`. So, take a close look at your selector. Voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: I fixed the typo and I get the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: You are using back ticks which can be interperted as template interpulation in javascript. use normal `'`

Comment: now you have funky `"`.  Seriously, why are you not just using normal quotes?

Comment: @Taplar, my macbook is glitching, for some reason it is funky backticks and quotes. fml.

Comment: @Taplar maybe he has a special keyboard set :D

Comment: lol, whatever it is, it's really strange that it went from one funky character to another.  like he's trolling us, >:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine as long as you use "normal" single and double quotes, not backticks or "smart quotes":

```js
document.querySelector("button[data-test='qa-cart-checkout']").click();
```

```html
<button class="ncss-btn-black fs16-sm ncss-brand pb3-sm pl5-sm pr5-sm pt3-sm mr3-sm u-uppercase css-1n4ymyz" data-test="qa-cart-checkout" onclick="alert('it works')">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: How do people get to use those strange characters anyway?

Comment: My macbook is changing it to strange characters, im so sorry.

Comment: Ah, that will explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript a Backtick means template literals.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

use regular `'` or `"`